# Can the Xxcha predict a special victory for Sol or Hakan?

Tags: rex

The Xxcha have the ability to predict a winner (solo or from an alliance).

**Can they use this ability to predict the special win conditions?**

IE: Can the Xxcha player predict a Hakan victory on turn 8 (from his special condition, and not from normal strongholds?)

If so, then the Xxcha player's best choice is to do this (imho) since then all he has to do is make sure no one wins by the end of the game, and have at least 1 unit in one of Sols special win location (preventing Sol from winning, and thus giving the win to Hakan - and subsequently to themselves)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [rulebook](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/rex/support/Rex_Ruleboook_web.pdf) on page 14 (emphasis in rulebook):

> **Xxcha victory**
>
> At the start of the game, the Xxcha player predicts a player and a game round. He records this prediction by choosing a race prediction token and a round prediction token. He places the chosen tokens facedown next to his race sheet and returns all unchosen prediction tokens to the game box (without revealing them).
>
> If the chosen player wins (alone or as an ally, even as the Xxcha’s ally) with **any victory condition** during the predicted game round, the Xxcha player wins the game instead.

Both the Sol and Hacan Special Victories count as a victory condition. The Xxcha player could predict a Hacan win on turn 8, and whether they Hacan win by stongholds or they win because no one else has, the Xxcha could snatch victory away. This seems like a doable strategy, as long as alliances aren't working to get the game done as fast as possible.